# Solving system of differential equations $\dot{x}=3x - 2y$, $\dot y = 2x - y + 15 e^t \sqrt{t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having problem with system
\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=3x - 2y;\\
\dot y = 2x - y + 15 e^t \sqrt{t}.
\end{cases}
Eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=1$, the only eigenvector is $V_1 = (1,1)^T.$ I write solution for homogenous system as $X(t) = e^{\lambda t}V_1(C_1 + C_2 t) = C_1 e^t \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+ С_2 t e^t \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Am I wrong? 
Because WolframAlpha and Maple both give same, different from mine, result: 
\begin{cases} 
x(t) = c_1 e^t (2 t+1)-2 c_2 e^t t;
\\ y(t) = 2 c_1 e^t t-c_2 e^t (2 t-1).
\end{cases}
I think I understand what to do further, but I am stuck here. 
Now I differentiate my (not Maple's) solution:
\begin{cases}
x(t) = C_1 e^t + C_2 t e^t;
\\ y(t) = C_1 e^t + C_2 t e^t.
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
\dot x = C_1' e^t +C_1 e^t + C_2' t e^t +C_2 e^t + C_2 t e^t;
\\ \dot y = C_1' e^t +C_1 e^t + C_2' t e^t +C_2 e^t + C_2 t e^t;
\end{cases}
Then substitute into original system
\begin{cases}
C_1' e^t +C_1 e^t + C_2' t e^t +C_2 e^t + C_2 t e^t = 3(C_1 e^t + 3C_2 t e^t) - 2(C_1 e^t + C_2 t e^t); \\
C_1' e^t +C_1 e^t + C_2' t e^t +C_2 e^t + C_2 t e^t = 2(C_1 e^t + C_2 t e^t) - C_1 e^t + C_2 t e^t + 15 e^t \sqrt t.
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
C_1' e^t + C_2' t e^t +C_2 e^t = 0; \\
C_1' e^t + C_2' t e^t +C_2 e^t = 15 e^t \sqrt t;
\end{cases}
Must not $C e^t$ terms cancel out now? I was expecting a system with only derivatives of $C_1, C_2$ inside. Anyway, i substitute $C_2 e^t = -C_1'e^t - C_2'e^t$ into second equation and get $15 e^t \sqrt t = 0$.

Comment: Please, no `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}`in titles.

Comment: Do you know any Laplace Transforms?

Comment: Laplace Transforms? Why?

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Indeed, why?

Comment: @Did ...I thought at the time that it would be amenable to those methods...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When solving linear systems of differential equations with real repeated eigenvalues, the solution form is given by the following

$X=c_1Ke^{\lambda t}+c_2(Kte^{\lambda t}+Pe^{\lambda t})$

Where

$(A-\lambda I)P=K$, and $K$ is the eigenvector.

Comment: It changes everything. I'll try now

Comment: I worked, that is where the mistake was. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

The formulas are equivalent. Your constants are related to $(c_1,c_2)$ through $C_1=c_1$ and $C_2=2c_1-2c_2$. The constants $(c_1,c_2)$ are nice because $x(0)=c_1$ and $y(0)=c_2$.

Comment: I still think there must be a mistake. I differentiate, then substitute and nothing cancels out

Comment: Please show these tries of yours, otherwise we are just whistling in the wind.

Comment: I put my thoughts into the opening post